# Multiple Auto-scrolling list of items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, loops

This is what I have right now

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

 var waitingTimeBottom = 2500;
 var waitingTimeTop = 5000;
 var animFactor = 20;
 


 autoScroll('.qbox1');
 autoScroll('.qbox2');
 autoScroll('.qbox3');
 autoScroll('.qbox4');
 



 function autoScroll(qbx){
  $q = $(qbx);
  $m = $(qbx + ' .marq');
  var mh = $m.height();
  var qh = $q.height();

  var xpx = mh - qh;

  var animationTime = xpx * animFactor; 

  function scroll() {
   $m.animate({'top': -xpx + "px"}, animationTime, "linear", function () {
    $m.delay(waitingTimeBottom).animate({'top': '0px'}, animationTime, "linear", function () {
     setTimeout(function () {
      scroll();
     }, waitingTimeTop);
    });
   });
  }


  if (mh > qh) {
   scroll();
  } else {
   console.log("too few items");
  }
 }

});
```

```css
.qbox1, .qbox2, .qbox3, .qbox4 {
 height: 60vh;
 width: auto;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 overflow: hidden;
 float:left;
 margin-left: 2px;
}

.marq {
 position: relative;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item {
 color: #39739d;
 background-color: #E1ECF4;
 border-color: #96bdd9;
 box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #f4f8fb;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="qbox1">
  <div class="marq">
    <div class="item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item">Item 3</div>
    <div class="item">Item 4</div>
    <div class="item">Item 5</div>
    <div class="item">Item 6</div>
    <div class="item">Item 7</div>
    <div class="item">Item 8</div>
    <div class="item">Item 9</div>
    <div class="item">Item 10</div>
    <div class="item">Item 11</div>
    <div class="item">Item 12</div>
    <div class="item">Item 13</div>
    <div class="item">Item 14</div>
    <div class="item">Item 15</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="qbox2">
  <div class="marq">
    <div class="item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item">Item 3</div>
    <div class="item">Item 4</div>
    <div class="item">Item 5</div>
    <div class="item">Item 6</div>
    <div class="item">Item 7</div>
    <div class="item">Item 8</div>
    <div class="item">Item 9</div>
    <div class="item">Item 10</div>
    <div class="item">Item 11</div>
    <div class="item">Item 12</div>
    <div class="item">Item 13</div>
    <div class="item">Item 14</div>
    <div class="item">Item 15</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="qbox3">
  <div class="marq">
    <div class="item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item">Item 3</div>
    <div class="item">Item 4</div>
    <div class="item">Item 5</div>
    <div class="item">Item 6</div>
    <div class="item">Item 7</div>
    <div class="item">Item 8</div>
    <div class="item">Item 9</div>
    <div class="item">Item 10</div>
    <div class="item">Item 11</div>
    <div class="item">Item 12</div>
    <div class="item">Item 13</div>
    <div class="item">Item 14</div>
    <div class="item">Item 15</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="qbox4">
  <div class="marq">
    <div class="item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item">Item 3</div>
    <div class="item">Item 4</div>
    <div class="item">Item 5</div>
    <div class="item">Item 6</div>
    <div class="item">Item 7</div>
    <div class="item">Item 8</div>
    <div class="item">Item 9</div>
    <div class="item">Item 10</div>
    <div class="item">Item 11</div>
    <div class="item">Item 12</div>
    <div class="item">Item 13</div>
    <div class="item">Item 14</div>
    <div class="item">Item 15</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Out of four, a single `qbox` is supposed to work like

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var waitingTimeBottom = 2500;
  var waitingTimeTop = 5000;
  var animFactor = 20;

  autoScroll('.qbox1');

  function autoScroll(qbx) {
    $q = $(qbx);
    $m = $(qbx + ' .marq');
    var mh = $m.height();
    var qh = $q.height();

    var xpx = mh - qh;

    var animationTime = xpx * animFactor;

    function scroll() {
      $m.animate({
        'top': -xpx + "px"
      }, animationTime, "linear", function() {
        $m.delay(waitingTimeBottom).animate({
          'top': '0px'
        }, animationTime, "linear", function() {
          setTimeout(function() {
            scroll();
          }, waitingTimeTop);
        });
      });
    }


    if (mh > qh) {
      scroll();
    } else {
      console.log("too few items");
    }
  }

});
```

```css
.qbox1,
.qbox2,
.qbox3,
.qbox4 {
  height: 60vh;
  width: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2px;
}

.marq {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item {
  color: #39739d;
  background-color: #E1ECF4;
  border-color: #96bdd9;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #f4f8fb;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="qbox1">
  <div class="marq">
    <div class="item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item">Item 3</div>
    <div class="item">Item 4</div>
    <div class="item">Item 5</div>
    <div class="item">Item 6</div>
    <div class="item">Item 7</div>
    <div class="item">Item 8</div>
    <div class="item">Item 9</div>
    <div class="item">Item 10</div>
    <div class="item">Item 11</div>
    <div class="item">Item 12</div>
    <div class="item">Item 13</div>
    <div class="item">Item 14</div>
    <div class="item">Item 15</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Why there is a conflict when multiple `qbox` are inserted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...
Change 
`$q = $(qbx); $m = $(qbx + ' .marq');` to `var $q = $(qbx); var $m = $(qbx + ' .marq');`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

 var waitingTimeBottom = 2500;
 var waitingTimeTop = 5000;
 var animFactor = 20;
 


 autoScroll('.qbox1');
 autoScroll('.qbox2');
 autoScroll('.qbox3');
 autoScroll('.qbox4');
 



 function autoScroll(qbx){
  var $q = $(qbx);
  var $m = $(qbx + ' .marq');
  var mh = $m.height();
  var qh = $q.height();

  var xpx = mh - qh;
  var animationTime = xpx * animFactor; 

  function scroll() {
   $m.animate({'top': -xpx + "px"}, animationTime, "linear", function () {
    $m.delay(waitingTimeBottom).animate({'top': '0px'}, animationTime, "linear", function () {
     setTimeout(function () {
      scroll();
            
     }, waitingTimeTop);
    });
   });
  }


  if (mh > qh) {
   scroll();
  
  } else {
   console.log("too few items");
  }
  
 
 }


});
```

```css
.qbox1, .qbox2, .qbox3, .qbox4 {
 height: 60vh;
 width: auto;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 overflow: hidden;
 float:left;
 margin-left: 2px;
}

.marq {
 position: relative;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item {
 color: #39739d;
 background-color: #E1ECF4;
 border-color: #96bdd9;
 box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #f4f8fb;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="qbox1">
  <div class="marq">
    <div class="item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item">Item 3</div>
    <div class="item">Item 4</div>
    <div class="item">Item 5</div>
    <div class="item">Item 6</div>
    <div class="item">Item 7</div>
    <div class="item">Item 8</div>
    <div class="item">Item 9</div>
    <div class="item">Item 10</div>
    <div class="item">Item 11</div>
    <div class="item">Item 12</div>
    <div class="item">Item 13</div>
    <div class="item">Item 14</div>
    <div class="item">Item 15</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="qbox2">
  <div class="marq">
    <div class="item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item">Item 3</div>
    <div class="item">Item 4</div>
    <div class="item">Item 5</div>
    <div class="item">Item 6</div>
    <div class="item">Item 7</div>
    <div class="item">Item 8</div>
    <div class="item">Item 9</div>
    <div class="item">Item 10</div>
    <div class="item">Item 11</div>
    <div class="item">Item 12</div>
    <div class="item">Item 13</div>
    <div class="item">Item 14</div>
    <div class="item">Item 15</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="qbox3">
  <div class="marq">
    <div class="item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item">Item 3</div>
    <div class="item">Item 4</div>
    <div class="item">Item 5</div>
    <div class="item">Item 6</div>
    <div class="item">Item 7</div>
    <div class="item">Item 8</div>
    <div class="item">Item 9</div>
    <div class="item">Item 10</div>
    <div class="item">Item 11</div>
    <div class="item">Item 12</div>
    <div class="item">Item 13</div>
    <div class="item">Item 14</div>
    <div class="item">Item 15</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="qbox4">
  <div class="marq">
    <div class="item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item">Item 3</div>
    <div class="item">Item 4</div>
    <div class="item">Item 5</div>
    <div class="item">Item 6</div>
    <div class="item">Item 7</div>
    <div class="item">Item 8</div>
    <div class="item">Item 9</div>
    <div class="item">Item 10</div>
    <div class="item">Item 11</div>
    <div class="item">Item 12</div>
    <div class="item">Item 13</div>
    <div class="item">Item 14</div>
    <div class="item">Item 15</div>
  </div>
</div>
```